# How to see the running time of a python program using terminal command

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, python3

I want to know whether there is a terminal command that displays the execution time for a `python program ?` For example using `time ./proram_name` to display the execution time for C++ program.  For example I used `g++ hello.cpp -o hello && time ./hello` in the terminal to build and see the execution time for the C++ program. And the result was :

```
Hello world!

real    0m0.009s  
user    0m0.000s  
sys     0m0.009s
```

I tried the same as I used in C++. But since there is no object file ie. hello.exe, created so it wasn't that much handy.

Comment: I don't see how object files are relevant here - can you please [edit] your question to include a minimal example that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: You can use "time" command. You just type "time ./proram_name" in terminal.

Comment: or `time python some_file.py` is fine too

Comment: And there is `/usr/bin/time`, read `man time`. Simply issuing `time` uses your shell's (`echo "$SHELL"`) builtin time measurement.

Comment: @steeldriver check now.

Comment: @NazmusSakibSibly so what prevents you from using the same `time` command for a python program? What does *"wasn't that much handy"* mean, exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use bash time like this:

```
time python3 proram_name.py
```

I would suggest to do this inside python. Basic example from the python manual:

```
import time

start = time.time()
print("hello")
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

You can use it to time the whole program but also to time specific functions. Far more useful than from bash.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `time` command in the terminal
`time -  run programs and summarize system resource usage`

- Example

```bash
time ./script.py 
script output
./script.py  5.37s user 2.73s system 99% cpu 8.109 total
```